# Screen scraping a two-column table with PHP

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom, screen-scraping

Sounds simple enough but I'm new to the whole screen **scraping** thing. What I have is a remote site http://www.remotesite.com (for example purposes) that has a schedule table with a structure like so:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="team">
      Team 1
    </td>
    <td class="team">
      Team 2
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The table is populated with a dynamic range of entries depending on the the number of games going that day where Team 1 vs Team 2 etc.

I've built my **scraper** to get a list of all the teams listed in the table and it works successfully. Here's the code:

```
<?php
// Load Simple DOM
    include_once("simple_html_dom.php");
    
// Scrape the Schedule
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $html = file_get_html("http://www.remotesite.com/schedule.htm");
    
    // Load HTML
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    // Get all the Teams
        $my_xpath_query = "//table//td[contains(@class, 'team')]";
        $result_rows = $xpath->query($my_xpath_query);
```

?>

And to echo the scrape I have this code:

```
<?php
    // Display the schedule
        foreach ($result_rows as $result_object){
            echo $result_object->nodeValue;
        }
?>
```

However, what this does is echo out the teams like so:

```
Team1Team2Team3Team4Team5Team6 etc, etc.
```

It is getting the pairs of teams that are playing against each other in the correct order but what I need to do is essentially echo out the table the same way I'm fetching it.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me!

Comment: What does _"what I need to do is essentially echo out the table the same way I'm fetching it"_ mean?

Comment: I'm wanting to get the table in full and echo it to the screen from my script.

Comment: Why search for `//table//td...` then?  Why not just an XPath query for the table itself?

Comment: I could do that but if they add any other columns then I could potentially end up with additional information I don't want or need.

Comment: So you *don't* want to get the table in full necessarily, then.

Comment: I used the term "full" because as the table exists now it is only 2 columns in it's entirety. What I DON'T want to do is pull the entire future table should they make changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your answers to my questions, I'd suggest just doing something like this:

```
$rows = '';
$teams = array();

// Pull team names into array
foreach ($result_rows as $result_object){
   $teams[] = $result_object->nodeValue;
}

// Extract two teams per table row
while(count($teams)){
   $matchup = array_splice($teams, 0, 2);
   $rows .= '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', $matchup).'</td></tr>';
}

// Write out the table
echo "<table>$rows</table>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the help thus far man, much appreciated. When I run your example I get "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded"

Comment: oops, typo.  try the above (specifically, fixed args to `array_splice`)